# sql server integration services feature missing from developer 2019 installation

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis

I downloaded and installed the developer edition from the [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads).  It sent me the SQL2019-SSEI-Dev.exe file.  Upon installation it doesn't allow me to install Integration Services, in fact, it didn't even offer it.  Some people thought I installed the Express Edition, but its definitely the Developer edition.  On the same machine, I do have Express as a byproduct of a Visual Studio installation, but it is side-by-side install.

Comment: well I stand corrected, I just ran Select @@version and I get the following Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-GDR) (KB5014356) - 15.0.2095.3 (X64)   Apr 29 2022 18:00:13   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 10.0 <X64> (Build 19044: )

Comment: I'm not sure how that happened as you can see from the link in the description I downloaded the right version.  It even says in big letters that I'm using the DEVELOPER EDITION install media

Answer (score 0):

The link above has the express edition and even though I downloaded developer editon I also downloaded and accidentally installed the express edition.